# Flutter canvas RadialGradient understanding

Tags: flutter, dart, canvas, radial-gradients

I'm trying to create an effect like a heatmap point, so a circle with 2 or 3 colors on a gradient and then likely blurred.

```
final paint = Paint()
  ..shader = RadialGradient(
      center: Alignment.center,
      colors: <Color>[
        Colors.green.withOpacity(0.2),
        Colors.red.withOpacity(0.5),
        Colors.blue.withOpacity(0.6)

    ],
    stops: const [
      0.3,
      0.6,
      1.0
      ]
    ).createShader(Rect.fromCircle(
       center: const Offset(1.0,1.0),
       radius: 10.0,
    ));

canvas.drawCircle(Offset(item[c][0].toDouble(), item[c][1].toDouble()), 8.0, paint);
```

However, whatever radius, Alignment, colors/opacity, shader center, stops I try, basically I just get a blue circle every time ?

I've also taken a look at [the dartui RadialGradient](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-ui/Gradient/Gradient.radial.html) (was after something like example 2), but I can't get that to work either.

I guess I'm missing something obvious, but can't see any Flutter examples of RadialGradient on canvas to compare to, any ideas what I'm misunderstanding ?

Comment: try to `drawCircle` around offset (1,1), for example `canvas.drawCircle(Offset(1, 1), 30, paint)` or `canvas.drawCircle(Offset(5, 5), 30, paint)` or something similar

Comment: Hi, it's exactly the same, but thanks.

Comment: i run your exact code (without any change) and with `canvas.drawCircle(Offset(1, 1), 10, paint)` - the result is: https://pasteboard.co/AoF9HAeueHgc.png

Comment: Thanks, maybe its my device, I'll try and borrow a difference on and test.